# Program doesn't enter the main function?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I'm tyring to create a server client connection but for some reason when I run the server code, it'll just give me the prompt, nothing happens. I put a printf as the first thing in the main function but even that doesn't happen. What could be executed before the main? I don't think I have anything that could cause a problem.

```
#include "md5.h"
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *handle_connection (void *);                               //gets a connection identifier and handles that incoming connection
int verify_password (char s[]);                                 // verifies if the input password is correct

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t connected;
    pthread_attr_t attributes;
    int listenfd = 0, conn_id = 0;                          // the listening socket identifier and current connection identifier
        //A: Creates the master socket 
    listenfd = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);   
    //B: the struct variable that keeps the socket address
    struct sockaddr_in sad;                                 /* structure to hold an IP address */ 
    struct sockaddr_in cad;
    struct hostent *ptrh;                                   /* pointer to a host table entry */ 
    socklen_t alen;
    //B: initialization of socket address variable
    memset ((char *)&sad, 0, sizeof(sad));                  /* clear sockaddr structure */ 
    sad.sin_family = AF_INET;                               /* set family to Internet */ 
    sad.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;                       /* set the local IP address */ 
    sad.sin_port = htons((u_short) 5000);                   /* set the port number */ 
    //C: binds the socket to its address
    bind (listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sad, sizeof(sad));
        //D: starts listening on that socket
    listen (listenfd, 100000);

        while (1)                                               // listens for incoming connections until program exits manually
        {
        int conn_id = 0;        
        //E: Wait for a connection request and accept it
        conn_id = accept (listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cad, &alen);
        //F: if the connection has been established it creates a thread that handles the connection       
        if (conn_id != -1)
        {
            pthread_attr_init (&attributes);
            pthread_attr_setdetachstate (&attributes, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

            pthread_create (&connected, &attributes, (void *) handle_connection, &conn_id); 
        } 
        }
}

void *handle_connection(void *arg)
{
    int conn_id = *(int *) arg;
    char recv_buff[1024];                                   // the buffer that is used for keeping the data read from the socket
    int n = 0;                                              // number of characters read from socket
    //G: read from connection into the buffer and checks if recieving data was successful
    if (n = recv (conn_id, recv_buff, 1024, 0) <= 0)
    {
        printf ("Error Reading");
    }
    //H: verifies if the password is correct and sends T if the password is correct and F otherwise 
    if (verify_password (recv_buff) == 1)
    {
        if (send (conn_id, "T", 1, 0) < 1) {
            printf ("Error Sending");
        }
    } else {
        if (send (conn_id, "F", 1, 0) < 1) {
            printf ("Error Sending");
        }
    }
        //I: closes the connection
    close (conn_id);    
}

int verify_password(char s[])
{
    char md5_hashed_password[33] ="24af484e92082ad450a63a69f924f10a"; // The password of server hashed by MD5
    char md5_hashed_text[33];                                         // Keeps the MD5 hashed text of input text
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    md5 ((uint8_t*)s, len, md5_hashed_text);                          //Finds the MD5 hashed of input text
    if (strncmp (md5_hashed_text, md5_hashed_password, 32) == 0)            //If the hashed value of the input value and the 
        return 1;                             // password is same the password is accepted
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you compiled it?

Comment: Throw it into gdb and break on main. Chances are you will get there.

Comment: @Ed Heal Yes, no error, no warnings.

Comment: This line looks suspect `listen (listenfd, 100000);`

Comment: You have a number of these which are warnings in my compiler "n = recv (conn_id, recv_buff, 1024, 0) <= 0". Parens would be good. BTW, I compiled and break'ed on main ok.

Comment: Mine blocks here: line 42, conn_id = accept (listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cad, &alen);

Comment: @EdHeal This is my first time working with sockets so I'm not too positive with the code yet but that line is in my main method no? so anything before that should be running fine.

Comment: @CharlieBurns That line will block because it's waiting for connection attempt from the client I think

Comment: Yep, my only point was that program is running and not lost before main.

Comment: So I commented mostly everything out. The uncommented everything I commented and it now magically works.